# Drawing from certain probabilities in Gaussian Normal Multivariate Distribution in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, statistics

I have the code and picture of the output listed below but I want to take random samples from these spheres within the specific standard deviations that have been plotted. The variable sdwith is used to set this in the code for the output of the wiremesh. The random.multivariate_normal does a sampling but you can't set the maximum probability or number of standard deviations to sample from. Is this possible in numpy or what is the best way to do this?

```
def sphere(r=1.0,npts=(20,20)):
     """Create a simple sphere.
    Returns x, y, z coordinates for the sphere
    """
     phi=linspace(0,pi,npts[0])
     theta=linspace(0,2*pi,npts[1])
     phi, theta = meshgrid(phi,theta)
     x = r*sin(phi)*cos(theta)
     y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta)
     z = r*cos(phi)
     return x, y, z
pet_bar = load('data_mod.npy')
num_vowels = 10
sdwidth = 1
npts = 20
cov_mat = zeros((num_vowels,3,3))
means_mat = zeros((num_vowels,3))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
colors = ['g','b','r','c','m','y','k','0.5']
for i in range(10):
     #change below to use different parts of the dataset
     indices = intersect1d(where( pet_bar[:,0] == 1)[0], where( pet_bar[:,2] == i+1)[0])
     # determines whether take all or >0 just takes unanimously heard correctly
     indices = intersect1d(indices, where(pet_bar[:,3] > 0.5)[0])
     pet_bar_anal = pet_bar[indices,-3:]
     cov_mat[i] = cov(pet_bar_anal, rowvar=False)
     means_mat[i] = mean(pet_bar_anal, axis=0)
     x, y, z = sphere(1, (npts,npts))
     ap = vstack((x.flatten(),y.flatten(),z.flatten()))
     d, v = eig(cov_mat[i])
     n = dot(v, (sdwidth*sqrt(d))*eye(3,3))
     out = dot(n,ap)
     bp = out + tile(means_mat[i], (npts**2,1)).T
     xp = reshape(bp[0], x.shape)
     yp = reshape(bp[1], x.shape)
     zp = reshape(bp[2], x.shape)
     ax.plot_wireframe(array(xp),array(yp),array(zp), rstride=2, cstride=2, color=colors[i%len(colors)])
ax.set_xlim3d((0,ax.get_xlim3d()[1]))
ax.set_ylim3d((0,ax.get_ylim3d()[1]))
ax.set_zlim3d((0,ax.get_zlim3d()[1]))
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d Gaussian Distributions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically used the full code below to set the tolerance (approx. number of points contained within the Gaussian sphere) to determine the sdwidth and alpha value at that tolerance. Then the alpha value can be determined for each sample from the multivariate_normal function using the below:

```
temp_a = dot(dot((points-mean).T,inv(cov)),points-mean)
```

If the temp_a is less than alpha value determined then the random sample falls within the sphere and is accepted. Of note, technically the accept/reject method should be used for the sampling done here but I have neglected this in the above. Most the math can be viewed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Full Code:

```
gauss_toler = 0.3
value = chi2.ppf(gauss_toler,3)
lb = 1; ub = 5; runpts = 10000;
if sdwidth == None:
     sstore = -1
     sdb = 100
     alpha = 0
     i = 0
     if type(which_people) == int:
         indices = intersect1d(where( pet_bar[:,0] == 1)[0], where( pet_bar[:,2] == i+1)[0])
     else:
         indices = intersect1d(where( pet_bar[:,0] > 0)[0], where( pet_bar[:,2] == i+1)[0])
     # determines whether take all or >0 just takes unanimously heard correctly
     if unanimous_only == True:
         indices = intersect1d(indices, where(pet_bar[:,3] > 0.5)[0])
     pet_bar_anal = pet_bar[indices,-3:]
     cov_mat[i] = cov(pet_bar_anal, rowvar=False)
     means_mat[i] = mean(pet_bar_anal, axis=0)
     x, y, z = sphere(1, (npts,npts))
     ap = vstack((x.flatten(),y.flatten(),z.flatten()))
     d, v = eig(cov_mat[i])
     for sdwidth in linspace(lb,ub,runpts):
          n = dot(v, (sdwidth*sqrt(d))*eye(3,3))
          out = dot(n,ap)
          bp = out + tile(means_mat[i], (npts**2,1)).T
          xp = points_mat[i,0] = reshape(bp[0], x.shape)
          yp = points_mat[i,1] = reshape(bp[1], x.shape)
          zp = points_mat[i,2] = reshape(bp[2], x.shape)
          poi = array((points_mat[i,0,0,0], points_mat[i,1,0,0], points_mat[i,2,0,0]))
          temp_cov = cov_mat[i]
          temp_me = means_mat[i]
          a = dot(dot((poi-temp_me).T,inv(temp_cov)),poi-temp_me)
          if abs(a-value) < sdb:
             sstore = sdwidth
             alpha = a
             sdb = abs(a-value)
     sdwidth = sstore
```